# Is it possible to use PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION in Pro*C?

Tags: oracle-pro-c

I've tried to use `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` in Pro*C but I get the following error at compile time:

```
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
...........1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION" when expecting one
of the following:

   ; into, using,
```

The relevant section code is:

```
  EXEC SQL EXECUTE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TABLE_TEST
        ( FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 )
      VALUES
        (:sOraFIELD1, :sOraFIELD2, :sOraFIELD3);
      COMMIT;
    END;
  END-EXEC;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it that Pro*C doesn't allow this?

Version: `Pro*C/C++: Release 11.2.0.1.0`

Do I have an alternative to obtain a similar result? I can't simply do `EXEC SQL COMMIT;` because then I would get the Oracle error 2089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session

Comment: In the end, I decided tu use a savepoint after the insert and if something went wrong after the savepoint I could rollback to it. That way, the transaction autocommit will save the changes made before the savepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this in Pro*c , however please evaluate the concept of alternate connection .
You can insert and commit using an alternate connection.

EXEC SQL AT "DB name" "your statement or in this case"  Insert ;
EXEC SQL AT "DB name" "your statement or in this case"  Commit;